# I want to get the URL of the active page in the browser in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, desktop-application

I am planning to build an application using Electron. What I want to accomplish is to get the URL of the site the user has open in Chrome. For example, if the user has Twitter open in Chrome, I want to get the information to identify it as Twitter, like https://twitter.com. To add, the information to be retrieved does not have to be a URL; it only needs to identify the site.

Comment: It turns out that it is possible to achieve this by sneaking a home-made extension into chrome.